# Comma, new sentence or semi-colon? Linking a statement with its justification/reason

Tags: punctuation, commas, semicolons

I need to edit this sentence of the form "[statement about an object], [explanation as to why the statement holds]", but there is no language that links the two clauses, like a "this is due to [...]". For example,

> "There is dark cat hair all over my sofa, the cat is allowed on the
> sofa now."

To me, a comma seems inappropriate here. There should either be a full stop in place of the comma, or a semi-colon, or the addition of "because", "this is due to the fact that", etc.

Any thoughts?

Comment: I'd use the period, but find the connection: *Apparently*, the cat is now allowed here. *So*, the cat is allowed on the sofa now? *Unfortunately/Well/Seems*.

Comment: I'd stick with the comma.  It makes a smaller separation between effect and cause than a full stop would.  I think that the reader is entitled to see the post-comma clause as the cause, and the pre-comma clause as the effect by their juxtaposition, and I don't see a necessity for a linking word such as *because*.  I also think we're moving off-topic for ELU and perhaps on-topic at Writing.

Comment: The comma is wrong; the first clause is complete and therefore needs a semicolon. But that's all it needs; no point adding any words, since the causation will be apparent.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean to imply causation, you must use because or the like. Juxtaposition does not give any such information, and in your example the flow cause->effect kind of implies "There's cat hair everywhere, *so* there's no point in fighting it *anymore*".

A semicolon would imply there is no causation between the two sentences, rather that they both mean something significant on their own. A full stop does not link them in any way.

One punctuation mark is left: the colon

> "There is dark cat hair all over my sofa: the cat is allowed on the sofa now."

Proposition : *clarification*

It's not as strong as "because" but it does imply the wanted effect<-cause relationship.

Comment: No idea why this was downvoted; by far the best answer here. 'Causation' is usually 'statement in initial main clause' causes 'situation in second clause'. 'Reason' is the semantic relationship here, as OP says. As _you_ say, 'because' spells this out far more clearly ... but this makes the sentence sound weaker. Perhaps << There is dark cat hair all over my sofa ... _the cat is allowed on the sofa now_. >> In informal writing, a terminal emoji?

Answer (score 0):

I would say that in this case, instead of having a comma, a ";" would be better. However, separating them would also do you well, into two sentences, such as:

> There is cat hair all over my Sofa. I should have not allowed the cat to come onto the sofa

Or, you could say:

> What a big mistake! I let the cat onto the sofa, and now it is full of cat hair.

Sometimes, just rearranging the sentence/s would make it sound better. It also depends on what you are intending to say (the example, I am presuming, is not actually what you want to say). Therefore, it *might* make sense with a coma.

Comment: Yes, I'd rewrite here myself. But ELU deals with what is correct, not with what is best writing practice, style ... that's for some other site.